# Getting the names and sizes of all the files in sub-directories using PERL

Tags: perl

I have written a routine to read all the names and sizes of the files contained in two folders and all their sub-folders. The root folder names are supplied in the command line arguments and each folder is processed in a for loop, with the details being output to a separate file for each of the two folders. But I am finding that only the filenames/sizes of the files in the two root folders are being output, I am unable to change  into the sub-folders and repeat the process, so the files in the sub-directories are ignored. Debug traces show that the chdir command is never executed so there is something wrong with my evaluation but I can't see what it is.
The code looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = $ARGV[0];
opendir(DIR, $dir) or die "Could not open directory '$dir' $!";
my @subdirs = readdir(DIR) or die "Unable to read directory '$dir': $!";

for (my $loopcount = 1; $loopcount < 3; $loopcount = $loopcount + 1) {
    my $filename = 'FileSize_'.$dir.'.txt';
    open (my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";      
    for my $subdir (sort @subdirs) {
        unless (-d $subdir) {
            # Ignore Sub-Directories in this inner loop
            # only process files
            # print the file name and file size to the output file
            print "Processing files\n";
            my $size = -s "$dir/$subdir";
            print $fh "$subdir"," ","$size\n";
        }
        elsif (-s "$dir/$subdir") {
        # We are here because the entry is a sub-folder and not a file
        # if this sub-folder is non-zero size, i.e has files then
        # change to this directory and repeat the outer for loop
            chdir $subdir;
            print "Changing to directory $subdir\n";
            print "Processing Files in $subdir\n";
        };
    }
    # We have now processed all the files in First Folder and all it's subdirecorries
    # Now assign the second root directory to the $dir variable and repeat the loop
    print "Start For Next Directory\n";
    $dir = $ARGV[1];
    opendir(DIR, $dir) or die "Could not open directory '$dir' $!";
    @subdirs = readdir(DIR) or die "Unable to read directory '$dir': $!";;
}
exit 0;
```

Command line invocation is "perl FileComp.pl DiskImage DiskImage1"
But  only the file names and file sizes of the files in the root DiskImage and DiskImage1 folders are output,  all the files in the sub-folders are ignored.
The code to change to the "elseif" condition is never met and the code never executed, so there is an error there.
Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) would be very useful for this.

Answer (score 3):

This check will most likely always be wrong because you're looking at the wrong thing.

```
   unless (-d $subdir) {
```

`$subdir` is the filename of a file or directory inside `$dir` so to access it you need to use the full relative path of `$dir/$subdir` just like you're doing here:

```
        my $size = -s "$dir/$subdir";
```

You'll also have problems if you do fix that `unless` check because doing `chdir` will also cause problems as you're doing it whilst in the middle of reading `$dir`'s content so will be in the wrong place to see later instances of `$dir/$subdir`.

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier to do logic like this without changing directories, but if you do use [File::chdir](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::chdir) or [File::pushd](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::pushd) so that you return to the previous directory when exiting that scope. However, this problem is much easier to solve by using a recursive iterator like [Path::Iterator::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Iterator::Rule) that handles the subdirectory logic:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Path::Iterator::Rule;
use Path::Tiny;

my $rule = Path::Iterator::Rule->new->not_directory;
foreach my $dir (@ARGV) {
    my $fh = path("FileSize_$dir.txt")->openw;
    my $next = $rule->iter($dir);
    while (defined(my $item = $next->())) {
        my $size = -s $item;
        print $fh "$item $size\n";
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use the `visitor` callback which gets passed both the full path (for file operations) and basename of each item:

```
my $rule = Path::Iterator::Rule->new->not_directory;
foreach my $dir (@ARGV) {
    my $fh = path("FileSize_$dir.txt")->openw;
    $rule->all($dir, {visitor => sub {
        my ($path, $basename) = @_;
        my $size = -s $path;
        print $fh "$basename $size\n";
    }});
}
```

Comment: Hi, Grinnz -  Many thanks for your assistance - after I installed the  Path::Iterator::Rule module from CSPAN this then worked !!

Comment: Yes, a few modules have such iterators which are sometimes really handy, just what you want.  As a note, I was taken aback a little to see that `File::pushd` doesn't (seem to) cleanly support a simple `chdir` back; what if I want to go back within the same scope? Can `undef` it but why not have a method? If not that, then I'd expect to be able to keep `pushd`-ing and then use my stack to `chdir` to where I've been; a `popd` of sorts. I don't see that it would take away the simplicity. Just a comment, it's a nice functionality as it is.

Comment: That is how pushd works in shell, but File::pushd decided to take advantage of Perl's dynamic scoping. Logically I think it would get confusing if it tried to provide both a scope guard and an explicit pushd/popd stack. You could emulate that by making a @dirs array at the top level and do `push @dirs, pushd $foo;` then `pop @dirs;` as your popd, so the objects are held by that array instead of the lexical scope.

Comment: Edited to mention File::chdir which is an older but similarly dynamically scoped approach, using `local` instead of a scope guard.

Comment: There are surely design questions there, and I imagine that it was a thoughtful decision that lead to the way the module is.  But it does feel it's missing a half (so to speak) -- I just can't go back (other than the gruesome `undef $obj` to destroy it); so just a teeny tiny little simple `chdir_back` or such. (I mentioned keeping the stack as another alternative but I agree that that might take things elsewhere.)

Comment: Hi, Grinnz - I was trying to refine the output from this routine by stripping out the directory paths in each $item leaving the file names only. I tried fiddling around with the $rule->iter method by testing the various additional options available, i.e using $rule->iter( @dirs, \%options);\%options); but could not find one that stripped out the directory path. Any advice on how to do this? Aain sorry if it seems obvious but I am a Perl novice. Alternatively we could afterwards process the output files to strip out the directory paths from each file, but it is better to do this interactively.

Comment: @Sproggit You can't strip out the directory paths automatically, each result will always be a full relative or absolute path (or relative to the starting directory if you pass `relative`) since it does not change directories and won't otherwise differentiate between the same named file in different subdirectories. You can use Path::Tiny to get the basename inside the iteration loop: `my $basename = path($item)->basename;` or you can use [File::Basename](https://perldoc.pl/File::Basename).

Comment: @Sproggit I added an example using the `visitor` callback option which also gets the basename passed to it automatically. Just remember you cannot use the basename for file operations like filetest operators, as was the problem in your original question.